# Blender building error 'fatal: unable to look up git.blender.org (port 9418)....or WSAStartup failed' Win64

Tags: command-line, versions, compile

[image]

im not a programmer, please help me like you would your grandma.
Windows 10 64bit, followed all the previous steps from [this page](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows#Download_Sources_and_Libraries_2) very carefully

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [building Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems)

Comment: reboot and try again. Have you built it fine previously?

Answer (score 1):

ok it turns out that there was an bug with the latest release version of git (v2.19.2.windows1) in which it was unable to open git:// urls
i actually found the solution on devtalk forum, which has a dedicated place for building blender issues, [heres the thread](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/buidling-blender-error-fatal-unable-to-look-up-git-blender-org-port-9418-or-wsastartup-failed/3648)